# SKScene with rounded rect

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Is there a way to make SKScene have rounded corners?  I know you can use SKCropNode to make rounded rects, but I wasn't sure how to do this in a SKScene.  My ViewController presents the scene like the Apple default template:

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView 
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

The reason I want to do this is I reuse my main GameScene with a tutorial in the beginning of the game that is in a container view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres my approach

[image]

```
let world = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "world")
var num = CGFloat(0)

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    let cropNode = SKCropNode()
    let worldMask = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rect")

    cropNode.addChild(world)
    cropNode.maskNode = worldMask
    addChild(cropNode)
    cropNode.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)

    let randomSquare = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    world.addChild(randomSquare)
}


override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    num += 0.1
    world.position.x += cos(num) * 10
    world.position.y += sin(num) * 10
}
```